# dependency issue with composer

Tags: php, laravel, npm, composer-php

I have two private packages: proposal and supplier
(I install them by adding URLs in repositories in composer json)

I installed the supplier package in the proposal by adding

```
    "require": {
        "atrialab/supplier": "^1.0",
    }
```

the installation is ok but now I need some functionality from the proposal package in the supplier

so I add this to supplier composer json

```
    "require": {
        "atrialab/proposal": "^1.0",
    }
```

now composer tells me to install proposal package requires the supplier package which is itself

Based on the picture I can install the supplier in the proposal but I can not install the proposal in the supplier

how do we resolve that?

[image]

Comment: Move common part that requires both packages to third package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have circular dependencies in Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778805/can-i-have-circular-dependencies-in-composer)

Comment: yes I think its good idea to have a third package

Comment: Why is this question tagged with Laravel and npm, but does not contain any such code? Also, why do you need two different packages that require each other?